# @Font-face problems in IE and fontsquirrel fix

Tags: html, css, fonts

I was able to use @font-face succesfully in chrome and in Firefox, but not in IE with this:

```
font-family: 'Market_Deco';

src: url('fonts/Market_Deco.ttf');
```

This didn't work in IE, so I tried adding this line after converting and adding the EOT file:

```
src: url('fonts/Market_Deco.eot') format ('eot');
```

That still didn't work so I removed the .ttf reference and went with only the EOT line. That fixed it in IE and broke it everywhere else.  I started looking on here and everybody recommended font squirrel, so I tried that:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'market_decoregular';
src: url('fonts/market_deco-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/market_deco-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('font/market_deco-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('fonts/market_deco-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('fonts/fontmarket_deco-webfont.svg#market_decoregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

I added the four new font files into my fonts folder, updated the CSS and now it works in zero browsers.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: `url('font/market_deco-webfont.woff') format('woff'),` why this line is using "font" and not "fonts" ?

Comment: Ugh -- that was actually the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling that font in your style sheet as

```
font-family: 'Market_Deco';
```

then it won't call the font, as it's actually called market_decoregular in your font-face rule:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'market_decoregular';
```

As noted,

```
url('font/market_deco-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
```

presumably should be

```
url('fonts/market_deco-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
```

Comment: Font Squirrel automatically renamed it.  Both names are correct.   It was the fonts folder on one version that broke the whole thing.  Thanks.